# How to add additional row in yii cgridview <thead></thead>

Tags: yii, row, cgridview

I want to add additional row like   and , thead-2 has empty cells. These empty cells will be used to 'collspan' in my table.

This is my table now:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10002593/Screenshot%20from%202013-12-31%2008%3A43%3A55.png

And so I would like to achieve the effect:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10002593/output.jpg

Thanks.,

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to do this is by creating your own `CGridView` class and overriding the `renderTableHeader()` method. Create your class like this:

```
<?php
    Yii::import('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView');
    class MyGridView extends CGridView {
        public function renderTableHeader() {
        // Your own table header logic here
        }
    }
?>
```

Take a look at the Yii source code to see how the default rendering is done:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/zii/widgets/grid/CGridView.php#L495

Comment: Ok, but how to call for one table? <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(....